# React/ Flux Frontend and Meteor Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, flux

I have been using React and Flux for about two months now and its been great with Flux unidirectional data flow.

I have just heard of Meteor and it's great with its publish-subscribe and DDP. I have a project at hand where I have created some of my React components already and done the application logic using Flux (alt.js).

Now I just want to use Meteor for my backend and use my React components with Meteor front end. Noting that it depends on other NPM packages (I use webpack for module packaging).

So can I use NPM packages in Meteor and still use JavaScript ES6?
There is a Meteor.js React package at Atmospherejs, but it's not the same as the original Facebook React.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest these 2 articles:

https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-webpack-from-the-ground-up-f123288c7b75

https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-webpack-react-router-a-basic-template-with-code-splitting-ac2f95d151e2

Very clear explanation of using webpack ES6 React+meteor stack.

Here couple example projects: https://github.com/thereactivestack/kickstart

Answer (score 1):

Meteor's existing Blaze rendering engine is actually only loosely tied to its publish/subscribe model. In fact, there has been significant interest in the Meteor community in using React as a substitute for Blaze -- so much that there is actually an [official integration](http://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/) in the works. (There is also an integration with Angular in progress as well.)

This integration aims to solve several issues to make using React in Meteor as painless as possible, including a ES6/JSX transpiler and the ability to use reactive Meteor data sources in React components.

Although there are some existing packages to use React with Meteor, the official integration by MDG looks great and you can look forward to using it with Meteor 1.2.

Additional links of interest:

- [Meteor: the missing infrastructure for building great React apps](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-the-missing-infrastructure-for-building-great-react-apps)
- [Preview of official React support](https://forums.meteor.com/t/preview-of-official-react-support/6150)

Comment: yeah. have seen those articles. But my app depends on other react components that are npm packages. how do i use npm packages in Meteor?

Comment: This is well documented; you might want to just try googling for 'Meteor npm packages'.